# Относительные ссылки для одного страшненького сайта - правильный путь?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, .htaccess, redirect, href

**Диклаймер:** *сайт писал не я, сервера не мои, адреса домейнов и ай-пи вымешлены*

Есть две копии сайта:
`http://www.mysite.com` - боевой
`http://11.22.33.4/~myusername/` - тестовый

Для примера, папка `css` находится в корне сайта:

```
http://www.mysite.com/css

http://11.22.33.4/~myusername/css
```

Сайт представляет из себя страшную мешанину `php`, `html` и `javascript`. Из фреймворков только `jQuery`.

В файлах сайта ссылки на файлы/страницы вида: "`../css/mystyle.css`"

На боевом сайте все работает как надо (на удивление)

На тестовом все выглядит таким образом:

- Если пользователь находится например по такому адресу: `http://11.22.33.4/~myusername/items/`, то ссылки на ресурсы работают (ну это и понятно, "`..`" поднимает на уровень выше и там уже эта папочка лежит)
- Если пользователь находится по следующему адресу:   `http://11.22.33.4/~myusername/`, то ссылки не работают (браузер ищет по такому пути: `http://11.22.33.4/css/mystyle.css` и конечно ничего не находит)

Как правильно починить ссылки? Может что-то добавить в `.htaccess`? Главное, что-бы вид был одинаковый и работало на обоих сайтах.

Спасибо вам огромное!